# Almacenar array de un loop

Tags: php

Necesito almacenar los resultados de una serie de consultas distintas en loop de mysql en un array para compararlo con otro y ver las diferencias y borrar lo que sobre.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

De momento no tengo nada de código excepto el query a mysql y el loop que lo hago con un foreach y en cada loop cambia los parámetros de la búsqueda automáticamente con un producto cartesiano.

por si sirve de algo pongo el codigo.

```
$UpTallicolor = CartesianProduct(array('tallas'=> $_POST['tallas'], 'color'=> $_POST['colores']));
    foreach($UpTallicolor as $DUptallicolor) {
        $CExisteArt = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Codigos","`que` = 'Codigo' AND `id` = '".$_POST["nuevo"]."' AND `1`='".$DUptallicolor['tallas']."' AND `2`='".$DUptallicolor['color']."' ");
        } //cierro el foreach
```

El resultado tendría que darme que todo lo que no este en el array generado del producto cartesiano se tiene que borrar de mysql.

creo que para comparar los dos array resultantes tengo que usar un `array_diff_assoc`¿seria la forma? ¿o solo con `array_diff`?

Mil gracias a todos por la ayuda

Comment: Es muy similar a la anterior, y creo que se puede usar lo mismo. ¿ No te sirvió el comentario ?

Comment: @Trauma si es similar :) de hecho es el mismo problema XD en plano si me sirvió, pero a la hora de aplicarlo no he conseguido que funcione de ninguna manera :_(

Comment: Ok. Te lo comenté basándome en la doc de PHP, no lo tengo instalado para confirmartelo. A ver si alguien te puede responder mejor.

Comment: @Trauma si como te digo funciona en plano sin problemas, así qué mi problema debe ser de sintaxis o a la hora de hacer las consultas. Mil gracias de todas formas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas declarar la variable que sostendrá el array a comparar fuera del loop y luego llenar tu array dentro del loop, finalmente comparas lo que necesites fuera del loop:

```
$array_final = [];
foreach($UpTallicolor as $DUptallicolor) {
    $array_final[] = $valor_para_comparar;
}

$resultado = array_diff($array_final, $array_a_comparar);

print_r($resultado);
```

Y así te regresa los valores que no están en ambos arrays...

Espero te sirva

Comment: Funciona :) mil gracias por tu ayuda